# Pointer to pointer syntax problem

Tags: c++, cuda

Lets say I have the following:

```
void init_gpu(cuComplex* d_hhBuff)
{   
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_hhBuff, memsize));
}
```

and I call it with something like

```
cuComplex *my_buff;
init_gpu(my_buff);
```

Well, when init_gpu returns, it is NOT pointing to the device memory that cudaMalloc allocated.

How do I modify this so that the caller of init_gpu will have my_buff pointing to the modified d_hhBuff that cudaMalloc creates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the pointer by value.  Change the function header to

```
void init_gpu(cuComplex *& d_hhBuff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `d_hhBuf` is a local copy. What you should do is pass the pointer by reference:

```
void init_gpu(cuComplex * & d_hhBuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you typedef:

```
typedef cuComplex* ComplexPointer;
```

And write a function:

```
void ChangeComplex(ComplexPointer ptr)
{
   ptr = new cuComplex;
}
```

And call it:

```
ComplexPointer cptr;
ChangeComplex(cptr);
```

What would you deduce by looking at call and the function (and **not** knowing the typedef) ? You would say, the `ptr` (`cptr`) is passed by value, and not by reference/pointer and won't change.

Now consider this call:

```
cuComplex* ptr;
ChangeComplex(cptr);
```

This is exactly same as above, you are actually passing type `ComplexPointer` - which just being passed by value.

Finally understand the changed signature:

```
void ChangeComplex(cuComplex*ptr);
```

And it is still the same - you are pass the **type** `cuComplex*` by VALUE, and not by reference!